# API OVH Sms sending

Tags: javascript, api, sms, ovh

Good morning!

My colleagues and I have been working for a few weeks on an application to send automatic SMS messages to notify specific people.
We use the OVH sms API, which allows us to use their service via JavaScript, the language we use for our app.
Unfortunately, we still have an unresolved problem: using the API in JavaScript, some numbers return an "invalid receiver" state and never receive the sms... However, by going directly through the sms sending interface available on our OVH client space, no problem and these numbers receive the SMS correctly.

Have any of you ever had to deal with this problem or have any idea how to solve it?

Thanks in advance :)

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator
(Sorry if it's not perfect, i'm not really good at english xD)

This is the line which we use to send the sms :

## Call OVH API to send sms

```js
this.ovh.request('POST', "/sms/" + this.serviceName + "/jobs", _params);
```

And this is what we get in console (for a a success case) :

```
{"noStopClause":true,"senderForResponse":true,"sender":"xxxxxxx","coding":"8bit","charset":"UTF-8","message":"VM002 : Bonjour, le livreur Test vous attend à l'accueil ! Répondez 1 pour l'accepter, 2 pour refuser ou répondez normalement pour un message personnalisé.","receivers":["00336xxxxxxxx"]}
```

Comment: DeepL is sooo much better than Google Translator ^^.. What does the code you use with the API look like?

Comment: Added my answer in the first topic, there's no place here and no line break ^^

Comment: Can you add this as a [mcve] to your post through an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49984154/edit)

Comment: Nobody got any solution ? :/

Comment: No solution Yet?